# UISlider minimumValueImageRectForBounds: and super maximumValueImageRectForBounds returns empty rectangle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I subclass `UISlider` in order to make the thumb smaller, and I want to override `minimumValueImageRectForBounds` and `maximumValueImageRectForBounds` to make their width 2px less. So my code is

```
- (CGRect)minimumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect stdRect = [super minimumValueImageRectForBounds:bounds];
    return CGRectMake(stdRect.origin.x + 2, stdRect.origin.y, stdRect.size.width - 2, stdRect.size.height);
}
```

The point is that stdRect is empty rectangle (0, 0, 0, 0).

Morover, if I explicitly set some rectangle like that

```
- (CGRect)minimumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(2, 0, 40, 8);
}
```

It doesn't affect minimum value image position at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing this also.  I wanted to add that it seems like the rect of the minimum value image is pretty much a function of where the thumb image is, which become way more obvious if you override `thumbRectForBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I just figured it out.  I wasn't reading closely enough.

Setting the `minimumValueImage` is not the same as calling `setMinimumTrackImage:forState:`.  The `minimumValueImage` is an image that gets displayed to the left of the slider and is independent what's going on in the slider.  Overriding `minimumValueImageRectForBounds` changes the dimensions of this image (the default size being 0pt wide) and the sliders frame is made less wide and shifted to the right as a result.  As I understand it, there isn't a way to modify the rectangle of the minimumTrackImage (such as to make it extend to the right of the thumb image); it is only possible to change the image.

I haven't really figured out the point of allowing you to set the `minimumValueImage`.  It seems like you could accomplish the same thing by changing the size of the slider and adding separate UIImageViews to the side of the slider.  Who knows.

Note that everything I've said here applies in the same way for the `maximumValueImage` and `setMaximumTrackImage:forState` methods.

Answer (score -3):

DO NOT DO THIS. This is an old, incorrect answer, by past me. I hate that guy.

--

As a general rule, you probably don't want to subclass the Apple standard UI controls. You might want to build it up and set those properties yourself instead (not sure if they are settable, but seems like they should be).

Comment: That's strange. Because these are two of four methods that Apple says to subclass if I wish. "If you want to customize the rectangle in which the minimum value image is drawn, you can override this method and return a different rectangle."

Comment: Yup - you certainly can do that, but if there are properties you can set manually I think you'll find it an easier path in general. Maybe I should have worded it as "prefer code configuration over subclassing when working with Apple UI elements." - apologies for being unclear there.

Comment: While I completely disagree with my past self of 2012, I'll leave this answer here as proof I hate rewriting history. (See what I did there, future self?)